# Autocomplete in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I want to make an autocomplete textbox. But it will be little bit different. Let me explain..

I have a static method in my util class. and I fill combobox from there.. such as

cs code here

```
public class MyUtil
{
   public static List<ProfessionList> GetProfessionList()
    {
       var liste= EntityHelper.GetProfessionList(false); 
        var profList = new List<ProfessionList>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> profession in liste)
profList.Add(new ProfessionList(){
                                  Profession = profession.Value,
                                  ProfessionID = profession.Key
                                  });
        }               
        return profList;
    }
}
```

public class ProfessionList
    {
        public int ProfessionID { get; set; }
        public string Profession { get; set; }
    }

and html side

```
@Html.DropDownList("cmbProfessions", new SelectList(MyUtil.GetProfessionList(),
"ProfessionID", "Profession"))
```

so it works very good..  Well I want to use same method for autocompleting in a textbox. I dont want to use any ajax functions or like that..

my cs code here

```
  public static List<SpecificTagList> GetSpecificTagList()
    {

        var list = EntityHelper.GetSpecificTagList();
        var tagList = new List<SpecificTagList>();
        foreach (string s in list)
        tagList.Add(new SpecificTagList(){SpecificTag = s});

        return tagList;

    }

public class SpecificTagList
{
public string SpecificTag { get; set;}    
}
```

and in html

```
 @Html.TextBox("txtSpecific", new { autocomplete = new
 SelectList(MyUtil.GetSpecificTagList(), "SpecificTag", "SpecificTag") })
```

I know that doesnt work. because TextBox(name, value) 
expects some value.. well how I can get that list without any ajax functions.. ?

p.s. : my util class doesnt derived from controller.. just a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have some client-side code involved here somewhere that you just decided not to mention--you will need some. HTML doesn't support auto complete.

If you don't want to use AJAX, then populate a hidden control with the list and implement some sort of autocomplete in JavaScript

Comment: thank you for your attenion. there is a sample here http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ could I create this kind of array from my funtion there? the way what you said, looks a bit weird.. but its possible also.. actually I want to do the best, what do you advise me to do ? thanx

Comment: You could certainly implement that code using a hidden control. Obviously, you'd have to modify it because the sample in your link has the list declared right in the JavaScript code. You could also generate your JavaScript dynamically so that the code does include the list items. Both ways should work just fine, although dynamically generating the JavaScript might make your code a little more complex.

Comment: thank you very much, I solved my problem with what you said :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with way of Mr. Jonathan. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    var specifiList=[];
    $('#hiddenspecif').find('option').each(function () {

        specifiList.push($(this).val());
    });

    $('#c2').autocomplete({
        source: specifiList
    }
    );

});   
</script>


@Html.TextBox("c2");

@Html.DropDownList("hiddenspecif",
new SelectList(MyUtil.GetSpecificTagList(),"SpecificTag","SpecificTag"),
new {style="display:none"})
```